# Apex Test Class : Send Email Error

Tags: apex, email, send-email, invalid

**Requirement:** Send an Email alert using a custom lightning component for selected records under few circumstances(Business logic) for which `Messaging.sendEmail` was used. Functionality working completely fine.

**Challenge:** Now the problem is when the test class gets executed.
I am creating a list of users and assigning the permission set in the test setup.
I used `System.runAs(quriedUsers)` to run a test block and getting following error:-

`Insert Failed, Invalid Email Address` and while debugging further I analyzed the email and name field are not exactly the same as I initialized under test class. I am getting like **automatedclean@00d3o0000008cbiuai** as an email that is not under the correct format.

Any workaround excluding `if(Test.isRunningTest()){}`

Thanks
Pranav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**automatedclean@00d3o0000008cbiuai** this email format is similar to email format for **Data.com Clean** user. You can not view this user in salesforce UI. When you query user record in salesforce, it returns this user.

[image]

I believe this user is being used for running the Test block.

How to get users that are created in test class setup?

Answer: Make the query on User and filter the specific user that you created in the test block. you may use the following:-

```
SELECT Id, Name, Username FROM User ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Sushant. It worked.